# github ssh key errors

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I am using on-prem setup of gitlab-ce . Everything was working fine with a single domain.
Later I setup different domains for https and ssh. ( requirement from organization )

```
ssh: ssh.example.com
https: https.example.com
```

Issues

```
https: git clone works fine with https.example.com

ssh:
I am having issue with ssh.example.com.
For PCs already added into gitlab. when I try git clone via ssh , it gives permission denied message.
for New PCs it works fine.
```

I have above 300+ servers to be using this setup via ssh.
Looking for a solution for above problem:

**also**,

How can I remove all ssh keys from gitlab server and add keys again ?

Comment: What else does the error message say?

Comment: @JimRedmond  , It gives these errors.
 " Permission denied  ( publickey ) ------------- fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.""

I have verified , Access rights are fine and repo also exists.